# Mulesoft error adding API implementation when selecting Design Center location

Tags: mule, mule-studio

New to Mulesoft and going through the initial tutorial. When creating a project, Selected "Specify API definiation file location or URL", selected "Design center" 
Prompted with user id and password and got the following error

```
There was a problem with the SSL handshake, please check your certificate installation.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any ideas as how to fix this? read that I need to add the cert to my Java or VM, but not sure how to do that.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in a corporate network, most likely there is some security policy in your network that is intercepting the certificates from Anypoint Platform and replacing them with custom certificates, to analyze the HTTPS traffic. This can be confirmed by capturing the traffic, for example with Wireshark, and seeing in the TLS handshake, in the Server Hello response, if the certificates for https://anypoint.mulesoft.com are modified. If yes, then you need to work with your network administrators to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below links.

[Please click for Solution for PKIX path building failed](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/95565/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-request.html?childToView=95587#answer-95587)

Thanks,

Manish Kumar Yadav